# Should my mom be added as a dependent in my dad's profile? (Parents are traveling together on B2)

Tags: b1-b2-visas, b2visa

I am currently applying for a **B2 visa** for **my parents**. I created a profile for my dad on the US Travel Docs website. While filling it out, I came across a **dependent section**. Since my parents are traveling together, should I **add my mom as a dependent**? If yes, then will both of them get a single interview appointment, and should I also create a profile for my mom on the US Travel Docs site?

Any help would be appreciated.